# "no such file or directory" linux

Tags: linux, installation, gurobi

I am quite a beginner in Linux and trying to install gurobi for linux. The installation guide says to move the downloaded file with the following command:

```
sudo mv ~/Downloads/gurobi9.5.2_linux64.tar.gz /opt/
```

When I run this, I get the response:

```
mv: cannot stat '/home/laukna/Downloads/gurobi9.5.2_linux64.tar.gz': No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: the file name is likely different as it reports (for example, the documentation may not have the most recent version number) - how did you download the file and does that give any clues? did you save it somewhere other than `~/Downloads`? you can use `ls` to explore a directory like `ls ~/Downloads` (you can also provide more expansive flags when exploring, like `ls -lhaF` or to taste and can use `man ls` or `ls --help` for instructions for this and most other tools, such as what those flags mean)

Comment: Probably because the file isn't there? This is an off-topic question btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tilde "~" symbol is "a Linux 'shortcut' to denote a user's home directory. Thus tilde slash (~/) is the beginning of a path to a file or directory below the user's home directory." (quoted from twiki.org)

So if your file isn't located in your home directory (which is what your message "No such file..." implies) then you need to write the absolute path to where that file is.  If you don't know, you can find it with

find / -name "gurobi9.5.2_linux64.tar.gz"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Linux is not recognizing the gurobi file, What is the file name? seems that is not gurobi9.5.2_linux64.tar.gz

You need check the file name in Downloads folder, replace in the command and run again.

```
sudo mv ~/Downloads/<FILE NAME>.tar.gz /opt/
```

Comment: I thought about that too, but unfortunately the file name is exactly the same...